# diffusion equation approximation

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm trying to code a matlab function that approximates a 1d diffusion equation with neumann boundary conditions, but I'm really struggling to understand the general approach for solving the problem. Could anyone tell me a general set of steps to approximating the equation using the theta method?

From what I understand it goes:

- create a matrix with size equivalent to the mesh size
- Fill the bottom row with values defined by the initial condition
- Fill the sides with values from the boundary conditions (how do i find these?)
- using the theta method formula below, calculate the mesh point above each initial value

$\frac{(u^{n+1}_j − u^n_j)}{∆t} = κ ((1 − θ)\frac{(u^n_j+1 − 2u^n_j + u^n_{j−1})}{h^2} + θ\frac{(u^n+1_j+1 − 2u^n+1_j + u^n+1_j−1)}{h^2})$

- repeat for each time step until the matrix is full

I hope thats at least close to the general process, but I cant understand how to work with the neumann boundary conditions.

I hope im not being too vague but any help would be great!!

Comment: Well, some more details about where you are struggling might help. From what you have written, it sounds like you have the basics.  When you ask about how you find the boundary conditions, there is no "finding", though.  If this is an assigned problem, you simply have to be given them.  If you are just doing this for your own edification, you have to make a decision about what they are ... zero, periodic, and zero derivative are the most common.

Comment: Advice: try and solve the problem with the smallest non trivial matrix you can design.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I've managed to solve it :)